Como cambiar colores en un listview mediante programación en xamarin
Soy nuevo en xamarin y me salto este problema. Quiero mediante programación cambiar el color de la letra y el fondo de los elementos insertados en un listview
        _listView = new ListView();
        _listView.VerticalScrollBarVisibility = ScrollBarVisibility.Default;

----> Aqui quiero cambiar  color de letra, fondo. El Background solo me cambia el fondo.
        _listView.BackgroundColor= Color.White;
        _listView.ItemsSource = db.Table<Company>().OrderBy(x => x.Codigo).ToList();


        _listView.ItemSelected += _listView_ItemSelected;
        stackLayout.Children.Add(_listView);

Como muestro en el texto anterior quiero poder manejar el color de la letra y el fondo en un Listview
